# Why is the present continuous tense used in "I have not found my ring yet"?

Tags: present-perfect

When I was doing an exercise on tenses, I found this sentence:

> I have not found my ring yet which I lost at the party yesterday.

My question is why we used present perfect? I asked some people and they told me that because of the word "yet", we used present perfect. But I need a reason, which leads me to better understanding of how to use tenses rightly. I think that it's better to use present continuous because the person who is lost his ring is keep looking for it, and the action is *continuing*, How much is that correct?

Comment: it is not advisable to accept an answer so soon. Please read [this](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) help section

Comment: @Usernew, Yes you are right, But I feel that your answer is good.

Comment: Still we must let others answer and give their opinion. Next time, wait for a day before selecting an answer as best :)

Comment: Find/Found is an action that occurs in an instant. By definition it cannot be continuous. So the present continuous would be nonsense. "I am finding my ring" sounds absurd!

Comment: @D_Bester,  very useful comment! however I remember an old song said "I'm finding you", is that common?

Comment: A song might use it differently just for a special effect. How about saying "I am finding lots of fossils here" meaning I am continuously finding a fossil and then another and so on. So the song might mean "I am finding you" again and again in a new way each time. Could hardly apply to a ring like that though.

Comment: Actually I found the song by Eric Johnson "I'm Finding You": The phrase "Oh I'm finding you" is used to indicate I will find you in the future. "Till I'm finding you" is grammatically incorrect but is used for special effect. Normally we would say "Till I've found you".

Comment: The phrase "Till I'm finding you" is unclear but it might mean: I'm looking forward to the time when I can pursue her continuously, finding her again and again. That idea is music to a woman's ears. Every woman fears being jilted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Present Perfect** is used when we want to express a past action the results of which still continues.

Example:

> - I have lived in Texas for five years. [it implies that I am still living in Texas]
> - We have known each other for the past ten years.[and we still know]

**Present Continuous** is used to express an action going on at the time of speaking:

> - We are searching for the wedding ring.

***NOTE*** This(Present continuous) tense is sometimes used to mark an action that will happen in the future;

> - I am leaving for Southampton tomorrow.

---

Considering your example, I can understand your misunderstanding.

> I have not found my ring **yet** which I lost at the party yesterday.

This implies that you still have not found the ring.[it implies that you are still looking for it.]

If you want to emphasis on the action rather than result, then use present continuous:

> - I am still searching/looking for my ring which I lost at the party yesterday.

**or**

> - I am still searching/looking for my ring that I lost at the party yesterday.